# How to embed an external application in a PyQt5 Window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to embed an external application into my PyQt5 GUI. I am not sure how to do this. This is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window,self).__init__()
            self.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
            self.setWindowTitle("orbis Orbis *time freezes*")
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: use win32gui module

Comment: what do you mean "embed"? Do you means display output from other program inside your GUI ? Like display external video player inside your GUI? OR you want to get text output from CLI program and display it in some Text widget?